# AppError: Bad response: 404 Not Found (not 200 OK

Tags: google-app-engine, nosetests, webtest

I have faced the below error while testing an API.

```
AppError: Bad response: 404 Not Found (not 200 OK or 3xx redirect for http://localhost/_ah/spi/AdminAuthentication.authenticate)
'{"state": "APPLICATION_ERROR", "error_message": "No user with the E-mail address \\"foo@bar.com\\" exists."}'
```

Here is the test function, I wrote

```
def test_should_not_authenticate_if_there_is_no_user_for_email(self):
    app = endpoints.api_server([AdminAuthentication], restricted=False)
    testapp = webtest.TestApp(app)
    msg = {'email': 'foo@bar.com'}
    resp = testapp.post_json('/_ah/spi/AdminAuthentication.authenticate', msg)
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_int, 404)
```

corresponding routing definition  of `app.yaml` file should look like,

```
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: api.services.application
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default it's expecting status code 200. 
http://webtest.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testapp.html

> To indicate another status is expected, use the keyword argument
>   status=404 to (for example) check that it is a 404 status, or
>   status="*" to allow any status, or status="400 Custom Bad Request" to
>   use custom reason phrase.
>   If you expect errors to be printed, use expect_errors=True.